# Chef crashes when installing gem

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra

Im using chef and vagrant as provisioner.

When I try to install gems as follows, the app crashes:

metadata.rb

```
gem 'faraday'
gem 'json'
```

default.rb

```
require 'faraday'
require 'json'

conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://127.0.0.1:8200')
```

This error raises:

```
==> default: Running handlers:
==> default: [2017-10-25T09:42:43+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: Running handlers complete
==> default: [2017-10-25T09:42:43+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 19 seconds
==> default: [2017-10-25T09:42:43+00:00] INFO: Sending resource update report (run-id: 7f4593f5-1c86-409c-95fe-988f09501740)
==> default: [2017-10-25T09:42:43+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2017-10-25T09:42:43+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
==> default: [2017-10-25T09:42:43+00:00] ERROR: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '5'
==> default: ---- Begin output of bundle install ----
==> default: STDOUT: Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
==> default: installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
==> default: users on this machine.
==> default: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
==> default: Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
==> default: Resolving dependencies...
==> default: Installing multipart-post 2.0.0
==> default: Installing json 2.1.0 with native extensions
==> default:
==> default: Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
==> default:
==> default:     current directory: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20171025-3434-1qh8whd.rb extconf.rb
==> default: creating Makefile
==> default:
==> default: current directory: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
==> default: make "DESTDIR=" clean
==> default:
==> default: current directory: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.1.0/ext/json/ext/generator
==> default: make "DESTDIR="
==> default: compiling generator.c
==> default: make: gcc: Command not found
==> default: make: *** [generator.o] Error 127
==> default:
==> default: make failed, exit code 2
==> default:
==> default: Gem files will remain installed in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.1.0 for inspection.
==> default: Results logged to /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-2.1.0/gem_make.out
==> default: Using bundler 1.12.5
==> default: Installing faraday 0.13.1
==> default: An error occurred while installing json (2.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
==> default: Make sure that `gem install json -v '2.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
==> default: STDERR:
==> default: ---- End output of bundle install ----
==> default: Ran bundle install returned 5
==> default: [2017-10-25T09:42:43+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

It seems that gcc is missing, but I can't install it because it tries first to install gems and then executes the recipe, so it crashes before I can do anything.

-- EDIT --

I've added these lines and is working:

metadata.rb: (Remove gem dependency from here)

```
depends 'hashicorp-vault', '~> 2.5.0'
depends 'build-essential', '~> 8.0.3'
```

default.rb:

```
include_recipe 'hashicorp-vault::default'
chef_gem 'faraday'
chef_gem 'json'
require 'faraday'
require 'json'
```

Comment: `make: gcc: Command not found` that means you don't have gcc installed. You need to install it, what is your operating system?

Comment: I know that gcc is missing, the problem is how I solve that dependency. Vagrant is provisioning a CentOS 7

Comment: Try running `sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`, this will install the usual build tools necessary on your box, including `gcc`. Not sure how `gcc` depends on installing Ruby gems, but pretty sure it's not the case.

Comment: I know how to solve it manually. The problem is that vagrant uses chef to provision the machine. And when chef tryes to compile the recipes, it crashes because gcc is not installed.

Comment: Can you edit the `Vagrantfile`? if so, why don't you add that command before the chef installation?

Comment: How can I install gcc on VagrantFile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chef-y way to install `gcc` is to use the `build-essential` cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

Add a shell provisioner before the chef provisioning?

In your Vagrantfile for example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provision :shell, inline: 'yum install -y gcc'
    config.vm.provision :chef, inline: '...'
end
```

Comment: That works, but what about if I change my CentOS for an ubuntu? That wouldn't work.

Comment: Then you would write some logic to detect what os you're running and execute the appropriate command. That kind of thing is quite common.

Answer (score 0):

Recipes are perfectly capable of running arbitrary commands, so if you know how to do it manually you can do it with Chef in a pinch. That being said you should guard any arbitrary commands so they aren't run every single time the recipe runs, only when they're needed.

```
execute 'sudo yum groupinstall \'Development Tools\'' unless <your logic for 
detecting gcc goes here>
```

Chef also has Ohai which gathers metadata about the run before it even starts, including what OS you're operating on, so you can make your recipe multiplatform by leveraging that.

https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html

```
include_recipe 'mycookbook::debian' if node['platform_family'] == 'debian'
include_recipe 'mycookbook::rhel' if node['platform_family'] == 'rhel'
```

Or, to give you more flexibility if you plan on having many platform types

```
possible_platforms = ['debian', 'rhel']
if possible_platforms.contains? node['platform_family']
   include_recipe "mycookbook::node['platform_family']"
else
    puts 'This platform isn't valid'
end
```